# Android InAppBilling v3 queryInventoryAsync doesn't return information about purchased items on other device

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm developing Android application with InAppBilling support.
There is following algorithm:

1. Check what user has bought and show it

```java
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(false, null, listener)
```

1. Then check what user can buy (in order to show some dialog for him)

```java
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skuList, listener)
```

And everything works fine on some device (phone).

Then I install application on tablet (using the same account) but information about purchased items is not available.

(Information about items user can buy I can get successfully.)

How can I get information about paid items (items user has bought) on other device (with the same account)?

**-- UPDATED --**

very strange use case:

1. User buys **2 of 3 available** items using Android InAppBilling on phone.
2. Check 2 just bought items on phone. They are visible.
3. Install app on tablet (or some other device).
4. Check 2 just bought items on tablet. They are visible as well.
5. **Buy 3rd the last one item on phone**
6. Check 3rd item on phone. It is visible.
7. Check 3rd item on tablet. **It is not visible**

What happens in source code:

**IabHelper.java**

```java
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, mContext.getPackageName(),
                itemType, continueToken);
...

ArrayList<String> ownedSkus = ownedItems.getStringArrayList(
                RESPONSE_INAPP_ITEM_LIST);
ArrayList<String> purchaseDataList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList(
                RESPONSE_INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST);
ArrayList<String> signatureList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList(
                RESPONSE_INAPP_SIGNATURE_LIST);
```

Consider number items 5-7 (have just bought 3rd item):

1. On phone we have info about 3 bought items
2. On tablet we have info about 2 bought items (1st and 2nd). **But why 3rd item is not available here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like its issue of Google Play. Can be fixed with clearing cache of Google Play app or reboot device.